# Is there a way to have a dark theme for resources editor in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I love dark themes in my development environments but can't find a way to make the resources editor (particularly strings) of Visual Studio dark too. My VS version is 2015 Professional.

Here's how I see it:

[image]

while the rest of the UI looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio themes do not effect some windows like resource editor and project properties dialog.

Looks of these windows are derived from Windows operating system windows style.

If you choose some high contrast windows theme then you can see resource editor in dark colors. But at the cost of all applications will have same high contrast theme.

But if you love dark themes so much then it wont effect you much. :P

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension for the Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise that changes the theme color of every element of the IDE. Just search themes and you get a lot of extensions and 90% of them work, you can even set up some transparent background for your coding environment and even add some music(mostly trance) that changes and helps you concentrate while coding.

Comment: Can you @MohitKumar and RohitRoy share which extension you found? Thanks! Also, my apologies to KillingFalcon for missing the deadline to give complete reward.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the resx editor using inspect.exe tool, you can see its a Winforms data grid view. It does not honor WPF styles. According to my understanding VS is built using WPF changes the themes via WPF style feature.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XLM editor instead of the table view, using **Open With/XML (Text) Editor With Encoding** and on top of adapting to your theme, it offers extended editing features such as reordering your data or multi-caret editing, find and replace etc.
Plus, you can use background images by using various extensions.
[image: resource editor in xlm editor]

Comment: Would this automatically update the .cs on save?

Comment: @ccalboni yes it does